# Symfony VichUpIoaderBundle. Uri generation

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I'm using **Symfony 3** and **VichUploader**.
Here's my config:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        photo:
            uri_prefix:         /uploads/photo
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/photo
```

Now in my twig template, if I use:
**{{ vich_uploader_asset(member.photo, 'imageFile') }}**, the uri generated is `/uploads/photo/test.jpg`, which doesn't work.

So i'm using **{{ asset(vich_uploader_asset(member.photo, 'imageFile')) }}**, which generates the right uri: `/my_app_folder/web/uploads/photo/test.jpg`

Shouldn't the vich_uploader_asset service generate the right uri by itself?
Or do I have to put `uri_prefix:         /my_app_folder/web/uploads/photo` in the VichUploader config?

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure `uri_prefix` with `/my_app_folder/web/uploads/photo` if `/my_app_folder/web/` really is the DocumentRoot of your app.

Comment: This looks weird. In the bundle docs, the uri_prefix example is `/images/products`.
With assetic, when you do asset(/images/product/), the **/my_app_folder/web** part is added automaticaly.